# Finding the constant in a piece-wise pdf

Tags: probability

The pdf is given by
$$
f(x)= \begin {cases} 0.2&\text{if }-1 <x <=0\\
0.2+cx \
&\text{if } 0< x< = 1\\
0&\text{if }otherwise \end {cases}$$

I tried to evaluate the integral for each at their limits and add them together and set equal to get c=1.2.
But that doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: c=1.2 is correct.

Comment: That doesn't make sense though if you evaluate it at x=1 you would get 0.2 + 1.2 =1.4 which is greater than 1.

Comment: A density may be larger than 1 at some points, as long as its integral is 1. For example the density of the uniform distribution on the interval (0,1/3) is 3 everywhere on this interval.

Comment: Okay. Did not know that. Thanks.